# Install memcached on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache, memcached, ubuntu-12.04, libmemcached

```
sudo pecl install memcached
```

It prompts:

```
libmemcached directory [no] :
```

Tried the default value and a lot of different directories and downloaded source. Sure do enjoy these vague error messages.

Where do I find the files it is looking for and what exactly is it looking for?

Searched for hours already and nothing seems to help.

I tried compiling from source, but I ran into a lot of warnings and error messages and to top it off the php-memcached project doesn't seem to contain a configure script.

```
./configure
```

"File or directory not found" this is the error. It wants libmemcached directory but I don't know what should be inside of that directory.

I just want it to load in php any way possible. This is on a development VM so it doesn't need to be production ready. Just needs to work.

[Edit]

I have memcache installed but I need memcached instead.

I'm using:

Bitnami lampstack 5.4.29-0 Ubuntu 12.04

[UPDATE]

I found this:

> So I recommend to use/install the official memcached extension from PECL and update your application.
>
> https://github.com/kajidai/php-libmemcached
>
> Else you have to install the libmemcached extension from scratch with the following steps:
>
> ```
>    download from github
>    unpack the file
>    go into the new folder
>    phpize
>    ./configure
>    make install
>    enable it within you php.ini
>    restart you webserver
> ```

got to this:

```
./configure
```

checking for the location of libmemcached extension... configure: error: Can not find libmemcached headers

More vague error messages.

[UPDATE]

I solved the issue by upgrading to 14.04. Seems that was the fastest route to solve my issue.

Comment: "Sure do enjoy these vague error messages." -> what vague error messages? What you've pasted there appears to be a configuration prompt.

Comment: Why is the package manager prompting me for a directory with c code? Should it not just download what it needs?

Comment: ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/configure --with-libmemcached-dir=no' failed

Very descriptive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the "libmemcached-devel" package with yum (RHEL/CentOS/CloudLinux) or the "libmemcached-dev" package with apt-get (Debian/Ubuntu).

Once installed, the default answer of "[no]" is fine because the headers will be in the system-wide default location of "/usr/include/libmemcached-1.0", which the configure script will find on its own.

NOTE: You may be tempted to install "memcached-devel", but it is not the same thing as "libmemcached-devel". Between that, and the subtle naming differences between the "memcache" and "memcached" PECL packages, I suspect there are several developers that need to be smacked.

Comment: I solved the issue by upgrading to 14.04. Not sure what to do with this question on SO. Your answer sounds the best. Seems I am getting all the smacks with down votes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed `memcached`?

```
sudo apt-get install memcached
```

That should bring in `libmemcached`.
And can you please update your question with "these vague error messages".

Comment: yeah tried the usual tricks. All the other requirements went smoothly. I have memcache installed but I need memcached instead.

Comment: What is the "sudo pecl install memcached" command looking for? If I knew this I could probably find it.

Comment: Updated with more info. The vague error message comes down to "file not found" I need to know what it is looking for in order to find it for it.

Comment: It is trying to automatically detect something to do with the libmemcached's source code header files and doesn't tell me what it is. I guess I have to start digging around in the source of memcached.

Answer (score 0):

First run this command

```
sudo apt-get install memcached
```

This will install memcached onto your server

To use memcache you must install pear repository  which will store memcache

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

If you do not have a compiler on your server, you can download build-essential in order to install memcache

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

now install

```
apt-get install php5-dev
```

and install PECL library

```
sudo pecl install memcache
```

Now write memcached extension in your memcache.ini file

```
sudo echo "extension=memcache.so" > sudo /etc/php5/conf.d/memcache.ini
```

Here you are done installing memcache, if you want to check whether it is instlled or not type below command

```
echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 11211
```

Followed the below article

[Install Memcached on Ubuntu](http://www.ultechspot.com/ubuntu-linux/how-install-memcached-ubuntu)

and it worked very well.